# Is there a way of "bevelling" a single vertex?

Tags: vertices

I want to take a single vertex and replace it with a face like this:

[image: vertex "bevel"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(edit: answer changed entirely)
(edit: thanks to moonboots for pointing out a shortcut)

- Select the vertex you want beveled
- Bevel it with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (you won't see any results)
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm
- Adjust settings as necessary

[image: result]

Comment: shift ctrl B is the shortcut to bevel a vertex   ;)

Comment: Or press ctrl B, then press V